# LNK2001 when running knn code

Tags: c++

I am trying to run the sample k-nearest classifier code from:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html
I have included these headers:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/ml/ml.hpp"
```

I am getting the following error:

> unresolved external symbol "public: virtual float __cdecl
>   CvKNearest::find_nearest(struct CvMat const *,int,struct CvMat *,float
>   const * *,struct CvMat *,struct CvMat *)const "
>   (?find_nearest@CvKNearest@@UEBAMPEBUCvMat@@HPEAU2@PEAPEBM11@Z)

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you compiling the code? Post the command that you are running or your make file

Comment: You included the headers, but did you also specify the libraries to the linker?

Comment: Thank you. I realized that I have to add the opencv_ml.lib in the Additional Dependencies under Linker-> Input->.